# Bargaining Data

Tags: data-request

I'm interested in finding a dataset that includes bargaining offers (both rejected and accepted offers). Does anyone have any idea of datasets or industries that collect this information?

Comment: Can you add few example of types of bargain you are looking for? This will help other to narrow down their search.